# Fluid simulation render works in viewport, but fluid is missing in image render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Fluid Simulation render works in viewport, but will not render the same.
The viewport produces the image I am trying to capture, but whenever I try to render an image, the fluid is missing. All the objects are visible to both the viewport and render engine. [image]
[image]

Comment: If the name of you water input is [Sphere] it may have it render capability turned off in the outliner.  Please turn on the render setting in the outliner.  That  is the one that looks like a camera.

Answer (score -1):

If the name of you water input is [Sphere] it may have its render capability turned off in the outliner.  Please turn on the render setting in the outliner.  That  is the one that looks like a camera.

Comment: The object labeled LiquidSim has all of the simulation objects in it, and the hidden sphere is just another lighting source.   --Blender file Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13BVFpDIG36NdNXH8lS5pKf6WtCqB8B3u/view?usp=sharing